# NullPointerException happens for some list items

Tags: android, json, listview, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I have a custom listview in my app which fills by JSON and I'm using bitmap to fill images in listView and I want to get a TextView value inside the list item that has been clicked

```
lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    try {
          hotel_id = (int) adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
          TextView id= (TextView) lView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.aNametxt);
          type_id_post = deleteIcon.getText().toString();

          backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(textView);
          backgroundTask.execute();

          Intent intent = new Intent(RoomList.this, RoomPopUp.class);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
    catch (RuntimeException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

and it works for the first two items of the list but for another item app will stop on hotel_id definition line and this is logcat when I click an item except for the first two items :

```
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at com.test.RoomList$1.onItemClick(RoomList.java:126)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2957)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3849)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
08-07 11:43:36.026 14747-14747/com.moalem.khane.khanemoalem W/System.err: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the point is all item's id TextView of the list are casting to one id but it for "SOME" items that id is null
is there anyone who knows what is the problem of this?

Comment: what is on line 126?

Comment: TextView id= (TextView) lView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.aNametxt);

Comment: `lView.getChildAt(i)` is null likely. That is beacuse ListView is working not as you expect it to work. It doesn't have as much views as the items in the list

Comment: well there is no reason for that my list got 6 items but for example lView.getChildAt(3) is null

Comment: how many items are simultanuoulsy visible on the screen?

Comment: 6 and when on print position of each one in logcat i can see each id off all items by clicking on them but for last four item this warning will appear and activity won't be started

Comment: anyway, that is not the way to do that. You  can use a `View view` parameter. It is exactly the clicked ListView row view

Comment: thanks for your help :)